# How to access local webpage with parameters in vb?

Tags: html, vb.net, process

I've scenario where i want open local web page (index.html) passing parameters in query which i can used in index.html but i'm having problem as it gives error as per below,

> **The system cannot find the file specified.**

**Vb.net Code**

```
 Dim url As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Url")
 url = url & "?id=" & txtFilePath.Text

  //Url example 
 "C:\Program Files\Products\Bella\index.html?id=232"

 Process.Start(url)
```

Comment: What does url give you as a value?

Comment: Something like this "C:\Program Files\Products\Bella\index.html?id=232" but if remove query then it opens up my default browser.

Comment: Try sending file:///C:/Program Files/Products/Bella/index.html?id=232 or better still file:///C:/Program%20Files/Products/Bella/index.html%3Fid=232. Also check that file:///C:/Program Files/Products/Bella/index.html?id=232 give you the result you want when you just paste it into a browser.

Comment: Also.... not too sure of Process.Start() Never used that. Is this a win form application?

Comment: I'ved tried encoding and decoding but doesnt seems to work. Ii tried above suggested url but it ignores the parameters.

Comment: Yes win application.

Answer (score 0):

i do not completely understand your question but i will try.

I do not know what the value of "Url" is, neither what the txtFilePath.text is supposed to be. but if you are trying to open a URL like

```
    localhost/index.html?id=example
```

in a browser, you should use that as the first parameter.

```
    Process.Start("IExplore.exe", url)
```

If you are trying to get the server to read the parameter you put into the URL, i do not know if you can make html-pages get parameters like that, maybe PHP or something else? But that should not make a difference at all for launching the browser and stuff, just a heads-up :)

But if you just want to open a static html file in a browser-window, you are, as far as i know, out of luck with passing parameters, but you **SHOULD** test for the existence of your file, so you are completely sure it exists in that path.

```
    File.Exists(url)
```

EDIT:
Since your url is "C:\Program Files\Products\Bella\index.html?id=232" i do not believe you could pass parameters, i think it will try to find a file with the extension ".html?id=232", which obviously does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are two issues:

**First:**

I think the reason for the error is you need to have "file://" before the URL (as Mych mentioned in the comments) in order to access a local web page. Many browsers will automatically assume the URL should have "http://" unless you specify that it's a local file.

Depending on your browser it may add more forward slashes, but two should be sufficient to get Process.Start to recognize it.

So your URL should look like this:

```
 "file://C:\Program Files\Products\Bella\index.html?id=232"
```

**Second:**

As far as passing a parameter to the URL the best way I have found (as jakobS suggested) you would have to use:

```
 Process.Start("IExplore.exe", url)
 'or
 Process.Start("Chrome.exe", url)
```

or whichever browser you prefer.

**So you could modify your code this way:**

```
 Dim url As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Url")
 url = url & "?id=" & txtFilePath.Text

 'Add "file://" to the beginning of the url.
 url = "file://" & url

 Process.Start("IExplore.exe", url)
```

That should get rid of your error and load the page with your parameters.

Hope it helps!